# CSS: border radius 3D straight effect and not curved effect

Tags: input, border, css

I'm trying to get this effect on my contact form, I'm doing this manipulating the input field. As you can see in this picture I create a 3D effect with the border.

**Design:**

[image]

I've read internet and so on and for now I'm using border-radius. The problem is that it gets close but it makes my curve too rounded if I add a higher number of pixels, as you can see in the picture below. If I add a higher number I not only get a curved effect but the border also invades the input field with its curve.

**Reality:**

[image]

Any suggestions how to make this effect with CSS? If possible cross-browser friendly. Please let me know...

EDIT ////////////////////////////////////// EDIT

I investigated and I'm now investigating to use `box-shadow`. I get a close look but not exactly what I need. As you can see on the top right corner you can see some imperfection. If I move this shadow of position then it really doesnt look too good. This is the ouput.

[image]

I'm combining border with shadow. This is the code I'm using up to this moment:

```
#teleCom li input{
    height: 12.12%; /*60px  */
    width: 48.95%; /*235px*/
    margin-bottom: 2.42%;/*12px*/
    background-color: #bdd4de;
    color: #aac1cc;
    font-family: light;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 2.5%;
    
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a7bdc7;
    border-radius: 7px;
    
    box-shadow: 5px 4px 0px 2px #a7bdc7;
}
```

Any suggestion or other CSS property I could use?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
box-shadow: 
    1px 1px 0px 0px #a7bdc7,
    2px 2px 0px 0px #a7bdc7,
    3px 3px 0px 0px #a7bdc7,
    4px 4px 0px 0px #a7bdc7,
    5px 5px 0px 0px #a7bdc7,
    6px 6px 0px 0px #a7bdc7,
    7px 7px 0px 0px #a7bdc7,
    8px 8px 0px 0px #a7bdc7;
```

Comment: Sorry, double checked. This is just perrrrrrfect! exactly what I needed. Didn't know you could do several shadows. cool!

Comment: haha, hackish, i know. but you can apply 8 layers of shadow. i'm looking for an alternative. but this one looks much closer to your requirement, right ?

Comment: The only thing that this invades a bit the input field. I know there is inset property, maybe there is some parameter to make the shadow not go in the input field?

Comment: the answer to that question. Simply more height to the input. Not ideal solution but it works for now. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

there should be methods for doing this the easiest would to use a "border-image" but it maybe wouldn't work out perfectly, but I recommend you to check it out here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

And if it didnt' work out, maybe causing some bugs you might wanna take a look into css 3d grapchis here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-2d-and-3d-graphics-and-animation-effects.html

Comment: The border image is not good for me because Im not using any image and also because it just does not work in our dearrest friend IE. Hate him... The css 3d graphics seems a bit very complicated for such detail. Do you have any other suggestions maybe? Thank you for your help